# how to use mongodb aggregate and retrieve entire documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am seriously baffled by mongodb's aggregate function. All I want is to find the newest document in my collection. Let's say each record has a field "created"

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $group: { 
        _id:0,
        'id':{$first:"$_id"},
        'max':{$max:"$created"}
    }
})
```

yields the correct result, but I want the entire document in the result? How would I do that?

This is the structure of the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52310da847cf343c8c000093"),
    "created" : 1389073358,
    "image" : ObjectId("52cb93dd47cf348786d63af2"),
    "images" : [
        ObjectId("52cb93dd47cf348786d63af2"),
        ObjectId("52f67c8447cf343509d63af2")
        ],
    "organization" : ObjectId("522949d347cf3402c3000001"),
    "published" : 1392601521,
    "status" : "PUBLISHED",
    "tags" : [ ],
    "updated" : 1392601521,
    "user_id" : ObjectId("52214ce847cf344902000000")
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a sorted `find`?

Comment: because I want to understand how to use aggregate

Comment: `aggregate` isn't well suited for this type of thing as you can't easily include the full doc in a `$group`, you have to bring in each field separately.

Comment: I saw somewhere an example that forEach-ed over the result of the aggregation and then used results.push( findOne ), but I couldn't make it work. All I want to figure out is how to get to the documents either filtering by some complex relation or even adding aggregate fields to a document.

Comment: I see in the comments that you are actually trying to do something different to this. Can you please edit your question to explain what you actually want to achive? And please include a sample document.

Comment: I edited the title to better reflect what I am looking for

Answer (score 21):

In the documentation i found that the **`$$ROOT`** expression addresses this problem.

From the DOC:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-documents-by-author

Answer (score 4):

```
query = [
    {
        '$sort': {
            'created': -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: { 
            '_id':null,
            'max':{'$first':"$$ROOT"}
        }
    }
]
db.collection.aggregate(query)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {

  $group: {
   '_id':"$_id",
   'otherFields':{ $push: { fields: $ROOT } }
  } 
 }
])
```

Comment: How can we convert the same query to use Paginations ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out. For example, I have a collection containing an array of images (or pointers). Now I want to find the document with the most images

```
results=[];
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$images"},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id", 'imagecount':{$sum:1}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id",'max':{$max: "$imagecount"}}},
    {$sort:{max:-1}},
    {$group:{_id:0,'id':{$first:'$_id'},'max':{$first:"$max"}}}
]).result.forEach(function(d){
    results.push(db.stories.findOne({_id:d.id}));
});
```

now the final array will contain the document with the most images. Since images is an array, I use $unwind, I then group by document id and $sum:1, pipe that into a $group that finds the max, pipe it into reverse $sort for max and $group out the first result. Finally I fetchOne the document and push it into the results array.

Answer (score -3):

You should be using db.collection.find() rather than db.collection.aggregate():

```
db.collection.find().sort({"created":-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: That makes sense in my example, but it still does not answer my question about how to yield entire documents in the result of an aggregate. Lets assume I really wanted to aggregate over a set of documents and the result were more than one.

Comment: In the aggregation pipeline, if you had just a $match phase, the entire document will be returned.  However, after a $group phase, there's no way the whole document can be returned.  If you think about it, it wouldn't even make sense.  When you group by a field, you'll only have those fields specified in the group phase for the subsequent phases in the pipeline.  Since those fields could be aggregated fields like sum() and count() (i.e., their values have been computed from several documents), it isn't logical to show the entire document corresponding to the result.

Comment: what if I wanted to get an aggregation from a collection with a subset of the document fields added to the result? Lets say I want all documents with a count of some aggregated field >= 5? eg. show me all posts with more than 10 comments.

Comment: We can add a $match phase in the pipeline, after the $group phase to filter the results of the $group phase.

Comment: Anand, can you give an example for the syntax, please?

Comment: Here you go: `db.foo.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$a", count:{$sum:1}}}, {$match:{"count":{$gt:1}}}])`.  I'm grouping by the field "a" and getting the count.  In the $match phase, I'm filtering the results for records with count > 1.  Let me know if this helps

Comment: Sorry, that did not work. Using your example I can run the following aggregation on my collection (see document structure above)

`db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: "$images"},{$group:{_id:"$organization", 'imagecount':{$sum:1}}},{$match:{imagecount:{$gt:10}}}])`

but that only matches the winning record

`"result" : [
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("522949d347cf3402c3000001"),
 "imagecount" : 20
}
]`
Maybe it is not possible to output an entire document with aggregate