# How to transform all documents of collection into an array of documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb

i have already a collection of documents like this way:

```
{"name": "apple", "cnt": 10}
{"name": "orange", "cnt": 15}
{"name": "banana", "cnt": 12}
{"name": "grapefruit", "cnt": 2}
```

i want to transform them into an array of documents and that should look like this:

```
[
    {"name": "apple", "cnt": 10},
    {"name": "orange", "cnt": 15},
    {"name": "banana", "cnt": 12},
    {"name": "grapefruit", "cnt": 2} 
]
```

Any suggestions on how can i do it?
Thank in you in advance

## EDIT

[Mongo group and push: pushing all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150205/mongo-group-and-push-pushing-all-fields)

i already tried the push editor

```
{ $group : {fish: { $push : "$$ROOT" }}}
```

but in vain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo group and push: pushing all fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150205/mongo-group-and-push-pushing-all-fields)

Comment: @Veeram i already tried ,you can see the edit section but vainly

Comment: [Group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) requires both id and accumulators.  Use [group on null](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-null)  to aggregate over entire collection. Something like `db.collectioname.aggregate({ $group : {
            _id : null,
            docs: { $push : "$$ROOT" }
        }})` should work as expected.