# MongoDB group documents by field name without specifying value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql, aggregation

**EDIT:** Solution found in the first comment, you could also check [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150205/mongo-group-and-push-pushing-all-fields), we achieve the same thing.

Let's say I have a collection including those documents

```js
[
  { name: 'John', fruit: 'apples' },
  { name: 'Zac', fruit: 'bananas' },
  { name: 'Sara', fruit: 'oranges' },
  { name: 'John', fruit: 'oranges' },
  { name: 'Sara', fruit: 'pear' }
]
```

Is there any way using mongoDB to group those documents by their field names WITHOUT specifying their values? I want all the documents to be grouped according to their names without specifying "John" or "Sara" for example.

What I am trying to achieve is to group them by name, so the pseudocode would be something like:

`db.collection.groupByField('name')`

and the desired result is:

```js
[
  [
    { name: 'John', fruit: 'apples' },
    { name: 'John', fruit: 'oranges' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Zac', fruit: 'bananas' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'Sara', fruit: 'oranges' },
    { name: 'Sara', fruit: 'pear' }
  ]
];
```

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$name", data:{$push:"$$ROOT"}}}])`

Comment: Yep, we both really wanted the same thing.
My question is for the less experienced programmers who are not familiar with aggregation, though.
Thanks for help, guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veeram answered my question in a comment, the solution is:

`db.collection.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$name", data:{$push:"$$ROOT"}}}])`

Comment: You did not ask about PUSH in the question, so the following query will be enough:  `{_id:"$name"}`

Comment: I didn't explicitly ask to `push`, but I did so implicitly by the desired result example, I needed an array of subarrays, each subarray containing one group of documents.