# MongoDB aggregate pipeline group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to build a pipeline which will search for documents based on certain criteria and will group certain fields to give desired output. Document structure of `deals` is

```
{
   "_id":"123",
   "status":"New",
   "deal_amount":"5200",
   "deal_date":"2018-03-05",
   "data_source":"API",
   "deal_type":"New Business",
   "account_id":"A1"
},
{
   "_id":"456",
   "status":"New",
   "deal_amount":"770",
   "deal_date":"2018-02-11",
   "data_source":"API",
   "deal_type":"New Business",
   "account_id":"A2"
},
{
   "_id":"885",
   "status":"Old",
   "deal_amount":"4070",
   "deal_date":"2017-09-22",
   "data_source":"API",
   "deal_type":"New Business",
   "account_id":"A2"
},
```

Account name is referenced field. Account document goes like this:

```
{
   "_id":"A1",
   "name":"Sarah",
},
{
   "_id":"A2",
   "name":"Amber",
},
```

The pipeline should search for documents whose 'status' is 'New' and 'deal amount' is more than 2000 and it should group by 'account name'. Pipeline i have used goes like this

```
db.deal.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            status: New,
            deal_amount: {
                $gte: 2000,
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: "$account_name",
        }
    },{
        $lookup:{
            from:"accounts",
            localField:"account_id",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"acc",
        }
    }
])
```

I want to show fields deal_amount, deal_type, deal_date and account name only in result.

Expected Result:

```
{
    "_id": "123",
    "deal_amount": "5200",
    "deal_date": "2018-03-05",
    "deal_type": "New Business",
    "account_name": "Sarah"
}, {
    "_id": "885",
    "deal_amount": "4070",
    "deal_date": "2017-09-22",
    "deal_type": "New Business",
    "account_name": "Amber"
},
```

Do i have to include all the these fields,deal_amount, deal_type, deal_date & account name,  in 'group' stage in order to show in result or is there any other ways to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need `$group` stage. You just need to add `$project` stage to output the account name from the referenced collection.

```
{
  "$project": {
    "deal_amount": 1, 
    "deal_type": 1, 
    "deal_date": 1, 
    "account_name": {"$let":{"vars":{"accl":{"$arrayElemAt":["$acc", 0]}}, in:"$$accl.name}}
   }
}
```

Comment: you are suggesting match, project & lookup stages in the pipeline and in that order.

Comment: Thanks Veeram but what's the reason for the preferred order.

Comment: Np. match is always first. project referencing look up fields so lookup goes before project.

Comment: Suppose In my case if i wanted to do grouping, what would the order be $match, $group then $lookup .

Comment: depends on fields used in group. If you don't use the fields from foreign collection you can do it before lookup else after the lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this query.

```
aggregate([{
        $match: {
            status: "New",
            deal_amount: {
                $gte: 2000,
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:{
            from:"accounts",
            localField:"account_id",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"acc",
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$acc',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
      $group: {
            _id: "$acc._id",
            deal_amount: { $first: '$deal_amount' },
            deal_date: { $first: '$deal_date' },
            deal_type: { $first: '$deal_type' },

        }
    }
])
```

You can do by :

1) using **$$ROOT** 
  reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150205/mongo-group-and-push-pushing-all-fields)

```
 { $group : {
            _id : "$author",
            data: { $push : "$$ROOT" }
        }}
```

2) by assign single parameter

```
{
        $group: {
            _id: "$account_name",
            deal_amount: { $first: '$deal_amount' },
            deal_date: { $first: '$deal_date' },
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to start with, your `$gte` operator doesn't work on the string field `deal_amount`, so you might want to change the field to integers or something similar:

```
// Convert String to Integer
db.deals.find().forEach(function(data) {
    db.deals.update(
            {_id:data._id},
            {$set:{deal_amount:parseInt(data.deal_amount)}});
```

Then, to get just the fields you need, reshape the document using `$project`:

```
db.deals.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            "status": "New",
            "deal_amount" : {
                "$gte" : 2000 
            }
        }
    },     
     {
         $lookup:{
            from:"accounts",
            localField:"account_id",
            foreignField:"_id",
            as:"acc",
        }
    },
     {
        $project: {
            _id: 1, 
            deal_amount: 1, 
            deal_type: 1, 
            deal_date: 1, 
            "account_name": {"$let":{"vars":{"accl":{"$arrayElemAt":["$acc", 0]}}, in:"$$accl.name"}}
        }
    }    
]);
```

For me, this produced:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "123", 
    "deal_amount" : 5200.0, 
    "deal_date" : "2018-03-05", 
    "deal_type" : "New Business", 
    "account_name" : "Sarah"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.deal.aggregate([{$match: {status: {$eq: 'New'}, deal_amount: {$gte: '2000'}}}, {$group: {_id: {accountName: '$account_id', type: '$deal_type', 'amount': '$deal_amount'}}}])`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: Also, can you please tidy up your formatting so it's easier to read your solution? See the other answers for good examples.